# OpenCV FPS on macbook pro

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I wanna make the capture fps to 60fps with opencv, but it seems that I can not go over 30fps. I guess the code is not wrong, but with the following code fps is still 30fps.

```py
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS,60)
while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow("frame",frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord("q"):
        break
```

Environment: python3.7.4, opencv3.4.4, macbook pro 16inch

Comment: Does this code gobble up all available CPU time? If yes, there is your answer -- i.e., you could enter "10 million fps" for your desired speed but that does not guarantee you will *get* it.

Comment: first check in documentation/internet if your camera/hardware can work with this speed.